# PS4 Streaming to Friends

Tags: ps4, streaming

Is it currently possible to stream live gameplay to friends over PSN? Or is this only possible via Twitch on a public stream?

If someone could go into detail over the options I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't that much detail to go into this with. Plain in simple you can only (currently) do a live stream over twitch or the other one, which is not currently syncing in my brain..... So you have two options for now which is twitch or the other. Though you could take clips with the share button and show them like 15 minute segments via facebook or something, but this will take a lot of uploading time.

Comment: Is there an easy way to invite your friends to watch that stream without them having to search for it?

Comment: You can send them the link to your stream, just copy and paste the URL into a message of some sort